Azure Classic Pipeline task download from a repository to an agent server without using a PAT or AUTH (best practices if possilbe)
Have files that get updated in Azure classic Repository
example would be:
https://dev.azure.com/mikedopp/Special-Teams/_git/mikes-access?path=%2Fapi%2Frtr2%2Ffront-end-api%2F_initUpdateMongoDB.js
*Would like to use a azure classic release pipeline task to download or pull the _initUpdateMongoDB.js and other .js files from the repository to an agent server.
Is this possible in a TASK  (assuming Powershell)
The only way I can think is to create a PAT but because it would be more a service level Im
not sure a PAT would be a great fit. Currently we dont use OATH Token.
Ideas?

By default, the pipeline agent has the authorization to perform this natively. No PAT tokens should be required.
In yaml, the checkout task does the appropriate git commands to download the code in the repository. By default, the checkout is downloaded to $(Build.SourcesDirectory) on the agent.
steps:
- checkout: self

Technically, this task is not necessary as Azure Pipelines will automatically include the checkout task in the first set of steps.
If you wanted to checkout multiple repositories, you would declare them as resources to the pipeline. The pipeline agent is granted the appropriate permissions to use these resources, so no PAT is required.
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: second
    type: git
    project: otherProjectName
    name: repositoryName

steps:
- checkout: self # self is an alias to the repository the pipeline resides in
- checkout: second

When using multiple repositories, the paths are different:

self: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/self
second: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/second

In a Classic Build pipeline, the first step in defining the pipeline is defining which repository to use. This is the equivalent of the checkout task.

If you wanted to checkout multiple repositories within a Classic Build pipeline, you would need to grant the pipeline access to the OAuth token, also known as $(System.AccessToken).

As there isn't a built in checkout task for Classic Pipelines, you could simply include a shell script to perform the checkout.
- pwsh: |
    git clone -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" <clone URL>

If you're just starting out, you should strongly consider using a YAML pipeline.
